# Como deixar a URL Amigável no ASP Clássico?

Tags: php, html, asp

Só consigo acessar o arquivo colocando a extensão dele, por exemplo clientes.php. Configurei o arquivo web.config desse jeito, porém não obtive resultado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>

            <rules>
                <rule name="home" stopProcessing="true">

                    <match url="^index/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?(.php)?$" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php" />

                </rule>


                <rule name="clientes" stopProcessing="true">

                    <match url="^clientes/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?(.php)?$" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/clientes.php" />

                </rule>


                <rule name="sobre" stopProcessing="true">

                    <match url="^sobre-nos/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?(.html)?$" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/empresa.asp" />

                </rule>


            </rules>

        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Como eu posso descobrir a versão do IIS? O cliente passou o acesso ao painel de controle da hospedagem, porém não encontrei nada sobre versão do IIS.

Comment: É simples. Olha os `headers` enviados pelo servidor. Abra as ferramentas de desenvolvedor, vá até uma das páginas do seu site e verifique os cabeçalhos. Vai ter o servidor lá: `Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5`. No meu caso eu uso o IIS 8.5. Depois, verifique se o *mode rewrite* está habilitado no seu servidor (Gerenciador dos Serviços de Informação da Internet - IIS).

Comment: A versão é o IIS 8, desculpe a demora.